# OnClickListener В RecyclerView не работает

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Есть фрагмент в котором `RecyclerView` и `Adapter` (код прилагаю ниже). Вся суть в том, что несколько месяцев назад создавал проект в котором работало все, а в этом что то не так, переписывал все из старого проекта, ошибок нету.

**Фрагмент:**

```
public class PortfolioTaskFragment extends Fragment {

private List<PortfolioElement> portfolioElementList;

RecyclerView recyclerView;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

public PortfolioTaskFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_portfolio_task, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    linearLayoutManager =new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());


    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();

    return rootView;
}

private void initializeData() {
   //Наполнение RecyclerView
}
private void initializeAdapter(){

        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(portfolioElementList);



    recyclerViewAdapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "qwertyu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "asdfzvzxcvzxcv", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
}
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ElementViewHolder>{

public List<PortfolioElement> portfolioElementList;
OnItemClickListener clickListener;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<PortfolioElement> portfolioElementList) {
    this.portfolioElementList = portfolioElementList;
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter.ElementViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_for_recycler, parent, false);
    ElementViewHolder elementViewHolder = new ElementViewHolder(view);
    return elementViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ElementViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.textView.setText(portfolioElementList.get(position).text);
    holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(portfolioElementList.get(position).photoID);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return portfolioElementList.size();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}




public class ElementViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener  {


    CardView cardView;
    TextView textView;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    public ElementViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_on_image);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_card_view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

}`

Answer (score 3):

Сам спросил сам ответил.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    clickListener.onItemClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
}
```

вместо `getAdapterPosition()` прописал `getPosition()`и заработало.

Может кому пригодится=)

Comment: вообще-то `getPosition()` [объявлен deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getPosition()) из-за проблем с работой в асинхронном режиме. Для вас это кончется тем, что возвращаемый методом результат не всегда будет соответствовать действительной позици. Вместо него рекомендуется `getLayoutPosition()` или `getAdapterPosition()`, каждый из которых имеет свои нюансы и проблемы. Стоит разобраться, почему от `getAdapterPosition()` вы не можете получить нужного результата и "не работает" тут не самое лучшее описание проблемы.

Comment: @pavlofff буду рад если поможете, сам сидел и смотрел на это часа 2, в голову ничего не пришло

Comment: @pavloff `getLayoutPosition()` работает без проблем, спасибо.